# Switching tabs in browser interfering with my timer accuracy

Tags: angularjs

Using the $timeout function in Angularjs, when I switch to another browser tab, the timer is delayed and I don't get the correct time.

How can I make this work correctly?

```
function timedcounter() {
        time = time + 1;
        $cookies.put("autoTimer", time);
        console.log("a");
        var hours, minutes, seconds;
        hours = parseInt((time / 3600) % 24);
        minutes = parseInt((time / 60) % 60);
        seconds = time % 60;
        $scope.timer = hours+ ":"+minutes+":"+ seconds;
        t = $timeout(timedcounter, 1000);

    };
```

Above code is used for counting time in secound,minutes and Hours.

Comment: I'm not an Angular.js guy but it looks like your approach adds in all the CPU and event and I/O wait time into each iteration, besides your 1000ms (1 sec?) delay.  You probably need to find a timer API method that interrupts once-per-sec no matter what happens, or create your timer to fire at an absolute time, and try to ensure that other activity doesn't delay beyond 1 second. You should be sure your timer activity is happening on a separate thread from UI, events and I/O. How complex you calculations / heuristics have to be depend on what kind of system timers are available to you.